# Regular expression does not match simple case

Tags: java, regex

What I currently have...
 `^((([A-Za-z])+([A-Za-z0-9\-])*([a-zA-Z0-9])+)*\.)+$`

Rules:

1. The first char must either be a "." or [a-zA-Z] (it can only be "." if the string is of length 1)
2. It must end in a "."
3. before any "." there can only be [a-zA-Z0-9]
4. other than a-zA-Z0-9 and . there can be - (hyphens) that is the only otther character set value
5. after any "." there can not be a "-"

examples that should match:
`.`
`a.`
`a-9.`
`abc.`
`abc.a-c.abc.`

that should not match:
 `-.`
`-a.`
`a-.`
`a`
`abc.-bc`
`ab-.abc`
`abc.a-@c`
`..`

currently it does not match `a.` which is one of the simplest cases. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: What means *"there can be - (hyphens) that is the only otther character set value"*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if it is going to match the only values that are allowed are a-zA-Z0-9 periods and hyphens

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan see rule 3

Comment: I don't see rule 1 implemented.

Comment: @SwimMaster *see rule 3* - except rule 1

Comment: Rules are in order of importance @Bohemian

Comment: Rule 2: _It must end in a "."_ Do you mean a literal `.` or the regex special character that matches any character?

Comment: @Abra must end in a period

Comment: I think there is also an unwritten rule #4 1/2: _Hyphens must have a letter or digit on both sides of them_.

Comment: @SwimMaster there is no "order of importance" of such rules, nor in regex.

Comment: @SwimMaster notice, I've edited and simplified the answer. Now it accounts not only for ending in `..` but also if `..` is in midstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative solution without lookarounds, you can start the string by matching a-zA-Z.

Then use an optional pattern that matches zero or more repetitions of the character class including the hyphen, and ends with matching without the hyphen to prevent it to be present before the dot in the repetition or at the end of the string.

With case insensitive enabled:

```
^(?:[a-z](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])*)?\.$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[a-z]` Match a single char a-z
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[a-z0-9-]*` Match 0+ times any of a-z0-9-
    - `[a-z0-9]` End with a-z-9 so that there can not be a `-` before the `.`
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\.[a-z0-9-]*` Match a `.` and 0+ times any of a-z0-9-
    - `[a-z0-9]` End with a-z-9 so that there can not be a `-` before the `.`
  - `)*` Close group and repeat it 0+ times
- `)?` Close group and make it optional to also allow a single dot
- `\.` Match a single dot
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MThH78/1)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not satisfy condition 3, e.g.  "a-."

Comment: @TonyR `a-.` should not be matched https://regex101.com/r/MThH78/1, it is listed at the `that should not match:` in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?!\-)([A-Z0-9]|[\-\.](?!\.))*\.$/i
```

This will also handle the `..` and `--` case.
Give it a try.

[Live demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0auFTU/3)

Let's break it down:

```
/
^              Line start
(?!\-)         Must not start with -
(              Start of matching group
  [A-Z0-9]     Match list
  |            OR
  [-.](?![-.]) A - or . not followed by - or .
)*             End group matching 0 or more times
\.             Must end in . 
$              Line end
/i             Treat as case insensitive
```

Answer (score -1):

taking it left to right:

`^` - start of stream, so far so good

`(([A-Za-z])+([A-Za-z0-9\-])*([a-zA-Z0-9])+)*` - in other words, attempt to match `([A-Za-z])+([A-Za-z0-9\-])*([a-zA-Z0-9])+` as many times as we can; 0 is also acceptable.

Let's try to match it once:

`([A-Za-z])+` - okay, that'll match the `a`.

`([A-Za-z0-9\-])*` - that'll match nothing.

`([a-zA-Z0-9])+` - the match fails here. This does not match `.`

Therefore, it doesn't match even once, and we fast forward right after that giant blob, after the *, and get to:

`\.` - this doesn't match; we're on `a`.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to fix it? Im not sure how I can do "if its length 1 then do this if its length 2 do this if its anything else do this"

Comment: Hm, this seems like a long explanatory comment put into Answer, which is intrinsically  not an answer :)

Comment: It explains precisely where the attempt by SwimMaster went wrong. There's also an SO rule not to just feed people their homework. If, @RokoC.Buljan, you feel this is not an appropriate answer either, you should flag this question as impossible to answer instead.